# Transparent PNG background in Windows Forms (Alpha blend mode)

Tags: c#, winforms, background, transparency, alphablending

Is there any new or easier way to edit the **Alpha Blend Mode** in *Windows Forms* so that transparent PNG images with "shadow" can be used as a background image for the *Windows Form* while persisting complete transparency and shadow effect?

NB:-

- I've tried the TransparentKey **and**
- OverRiding OnPaintBucket too

Comment: In WPF it is simple, in WinForms it may require WinAPI invocation

Comment: @ElliotTereschuk Thanks, but i really wanna know if there are any new ways to go about the ***Alpha Blend Mode*** in Win-form c#

Comment: @dbkonxepts winforms is a really old technology no one cares about anymore, and which doesn't support anything. That's why everytime you ask *"how to do X in winforms"* the answer is *"winforms doesn't support that. Use WPF instead*. WPF is a newer technology that replaces archaic winforms and allows a much greater level of customization in order to create [Much Richer](http://www.istartedsomething.com/20091124/razorfone-conceptual-windows7-wpf-multi-touch-retail/) UIs.

Comment: Thanks I have switched to WPF fully now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Over time I realise that for a more intuitive and elegant UI, *Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF)* offers more possibilities, than *Windows Forms.*

Nonetheless, there are several *Windows Forms* libraries available to suit the need for elegant UI in windows desktop programming.
e.g [DevExpress](https://www.devexpress.com/products/net/controls/winforms/) etc

Also here is an [article posted on CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1822/Per-Pixel-Alpha-Blend-in-C) attempting the *Windows Forms* Alpha blend mode